# Unable to insert an article into MySQL Python

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I'm trying to insert full article to MySQL database, but it didn't work..
i think i have an encoding issues because when i print, it started 
with `'[u'` .. i've tried some code but it didn't work. the content/article might be containing `,` and `"` resulting the sql text messed up

this is my code, it raising error input..

```
    k1 = str(mmhtml)
    for filde in cur.fetchall():
         faliase = filde[0]
         fpattern = filde[1]
         furutan = filde[2]
         fopsi = filde[3]
         freplacer = filde[4]
         k1 = re.sub(fpattern , freplacer, k1)
         k2 = k1.encode('ascii')

    Item['konten'] = k2.strip() 

    sqlinsert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tb_hasil(title, \
            datee, content, author, ling) \
            VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )" % \
            (jdl, tgl, k2.strip() , sauto,str(response.url))
    try:
         cur.execute(sqlinsert)
    except:
         print "error input"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: There are multiple issues at play here and you provide very little details about your input. It seems you're passing a list as an argument (`'[u'` as a result of string formatting). For starters, **never pass values using string formatting** (the `%` operator here). You simply shouldn't make a habit of it. Instead use placeholders/prepared statements. Strip the single quotation marks from around the `%s` formatters and pass the argument tuple separately to `cur.execute()`: `cur.execute(sqlinsert, (jdl, tgl, ...))`. That way you don't have to worry about escaping yourself.

Comment: This will not fix your code, but is a step towards safer code in general.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thank you for the reply , i'm trying to implement your suggestion.. i'm new in python, so i did it based on examples that i found

Comment: You should edit your question a bit, if you want good answers. Try to keep it minimal, but do make it complete: include just the bits that you think are relevant and include all inputs, variables, DB schemas etc. This does not mean a code dump, you don't have to paste your own code verbatim. The code should be verifiable as is. Make it clear what you expect as output and what you're actually getting. "because when i print, it started with '[u' .." is really, really vague.

Comment: @IljaEverilä okay i understand , thanks for the suggestion.. i'm sorry because i'm new here

Answer (score 0):

Hi which library do you use?

As far as i know the most libraries implements DB-API commons. So you can send the data via parameterization which prevents sql injections.

I am using oursql in python and the syntax is:

```
curs.execute('SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE `col1` = ? AND `col2` = ?',
(42, -3))
```

so you replace the values with a *?* and pass the parameters in a tuple

```
//curs.execute("... INTO Values (?, ?, ?)", (1,2,3))
```

Comment: it also follows the DB-API rules:

just with %s than ? e.g. //curs.execute("... INTO Values (%s, %s, %s)", (1,2,3))